# CDK v2 VPC subnet faild to create VPC id not found

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm relatively new to CDK and Typescript. I'm attemption to create a custom Vpc. Ive run into an error if i try to deploy it. My error is as follows.

```
CREATE_FAILED | AWS::EC2::RouteTable | PrivateDatabaseSubnet/RouteTable (PrivateDatabaseSubnetRouteTableE95C2B02) 
Resource handler returned message: "The vpc ID 'TemplateVpc' does not exist (Service: Ec2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6bd6e0fa-2b60-4834-852b-a24dec883062)" (RequestToken: eb4359e5-948a-3e2a-47d8-c27fc117b29c, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

This is my code

```
import { Duration, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import {Vpc, Subnet} from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import {GatewayVpcEndpoint} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";

export class CdkVpcStack extends Stack {
  readonly vpc : Vpc;
  readonly publicSubnet: Subnet;
  readonly privateDatabaseSubnet: Subnet;
  readonly privateApiSubnet: Subnet;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const vpcName= "TempVpc";
    this.vpc = new Vpc(this, 'TemplateVpc', {
      ipAddresses: ec2.IpAddresses.cidr('10.0.0.0/16'),
      vpcName: vpcName,
      maxAzs: 2,
      createInternetGateway: true,
      natGateways: 1,
    });
    this.publicSubnet = new ec2.PublicSubnet(this, 'PublicSubnet', {
      availabilityZone: 'eu-west-1a',
      cidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/24',
      vpcId: 'TemplateVpc',
      mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true,
    });
    this.privateDatabaseSubnet = new ec2.PrivateSubnet(this, 'PrivateDatabaseSubnet', {
      availabilityZone: 'eu-west-1b',
      cidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/28',
      vpcId: 'TemplateVpc',
    });
    this.privateApiSubnet = new ec2.PrivateSubnet(this, 'PrivateApiSubnet', {
      availabilityZone: 'eu-west-1a',
      cidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/24',
      vpcId: 'TemplateVpc',
    });
  }}
```

Im hoping to create a Vpc where i have control over the subnets AZs and ID

Comment: Try `vpcId: this.vpc.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPC ID is something like this `vpc-1234567890abcdef0`.
It will be generated by AWS automatically, when you create a VPC. Therefore, you shouldn't hardcode VPC ID.
You can **use `this.vpc.vpcId` to retrieve [vpcId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.Vpc.html#vpcid) attribute**.

Please try the following code

```js
import { Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Vpc, Subnet } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';

import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class CdkVpcStack extends Stack {
  readonly vpc: Vpc;
  readonly publicSubnet: Subnet;
  readonly privateDatabaseSubnet: Subnet;
  readonly privateApiSubnet: Subnet;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const vpcName = "TempVpc";
    this.vpc = new Vpc(this, 'TemplateVpc', {
      ipAddresses: ec2.IpAddresses.cidr('10.0.0.0/16'),
      vpcName: vpcName,
      maxAzs: 2,
      createInternetGateway: true,
      natGateways: 1,
    });
    this.publicSubnet = new ec2.PublicSubnet(this, 'PublicSubnet', {
      availabilityZone: 'eu-west-1a',
      cidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/24',
      vpcId: this.vpc.vpcId,
      mapPublicIpOnLaunch: true,
    });
    this.privateDatabaseSubnet = new ec2.PrivateSubnet(this, 'PrivateDatabaseSubnet', {
      availabilityZone: 'eu-west-1b',
      cidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/28',
      vpcId: this.vpc.vpcId,
    });
    this.privateApiSubnet = new ec2.PrivateSubnet(this, 'PrivateApiSubnet', {
      availabilityZone: 'eu-west-1a',
      cidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/24',
      vpcId: this.vpc.vpcId,
    });
  }
}
```